# Can my sublime check if the javascript method exists, like Eclipse does it with java?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am a web-developer. The people in my office are mostly java developers. Here is my example:

---

Let's assume i have a java-class called `foo` which has a single method called `bar()`. When my colleague writes

```
foo.bb
```

eclipse already tells him immediately, that this won't work.

-

When i have a JavaScript object called `foo` which has a single method called `bar()` i can write

```
foo.bba()
```

and sublime won't say a word.

---

To fix this issue i assume that sublime would have to run something like a headless browser in the background like eclipse runs a compiler all the time.

So, is there anything like that?

Comment: Consider using TypeScript.

Comment: Sublime Text is a text editor while eclipse is an IDE. Java is a strong typed language while javascript has dynamic typing (duck typing) that makes harder to implement IDE-like functinality. I use WebStorm IDE for javascript development, for me it is the best, it has a 30 day trial but after that you have to pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime is just a text-editor, so it does not have these features out of the box.

However, there are many plugins that can produce the behavior of an IDE. [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) looks like it has the features you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java)

tern.java integrates [ternjs](http://ternjs.net/doc/demo.html) inside Eclipse and provides a semantic/type checking [JavaScript validator](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter-Lint). Here a screenshot with your sample:

[image]

This validator uses [tern-lint](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern-lint) that you can use with other editor like [Atom](https://github.com/tststs/atom-ternjs), [Emacs](https://github.com/katspaugh/tern-lint.el). I hope that Sublime will integrate it one day. See [issue 46](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_sublime/issues/46)